# how can I return the sum (amount) sum(total_price) for each distinct currency that the user has made a transaction with

Tags: django, database

I'm trying to return a query set in django that returns the total amount purchased SUM(amount), total price paid SUM(total_price) for each distinct currency that the user has made transactions with. Is this possiible? advice would be very much appreciated

Transaction model below

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    date_purchased = models.DateTimeField()
    note = models.TextField(default="")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Function below

```
@login_required
def portfolio(request):

    sum_amount = Sum('amount')
    sum_total_price = Sum('total_price')

    context = {
        'transactions': Transaction.objects.filter(owner=request.user).annotate(
            current_amount=sum_amount,
            purchased_amount=sum_total_price
        )
    }
    return render(request, 'webapp/portfolio.html', context, {'title': 'Portfolio'})
```

HTML below

```
            {% for transaction in transactions %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{transaction.current_amount}}</td>
                <td>{{transaction.purchased_amount}}</td>

            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

SaleForm Below

```
class SaleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    amount_sold = forms.IntegerField()
    total_price_sold = forms.DecimalField()
    date_sold = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'type': 'date'}
        )
    )
    note = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Keep a Note?'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Sale
        fields = ('date_sold', 'amount_sold', 'total_price_sold', 'note')

        labels = {
            'date_sold': _('Sale Date'),
        }
        help_texts = {
            'date_sold': 'Use Calendar to enter date',
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **GROUP BY** in Django ORM as

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Sum

Transaction.objects.filter(owner=request.user).values('currency').annotate(
    sum_amount=Sum('amount'),
    sum_total_price=Sum('total_price'))
```

then the view becomes,

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Sum


@login_required
def portfolio(request):
    context = {
        'transactions': Transaction.objects.filter(owner=request.user).values('currency').annotate(
            sum_amount=Sum('amount'),
            sum_total_price=Sum('total_price'))
    }
    return render(request, 'webapp/portfolio.html', context, {'title': 'Portfolio'})
```

Comment: Thanks @JPG., do you know how I can also currency value to what is returned

Comment: Currency value? I don't understand that

Comment: in my html I want to add another row to the table that will show the currency

Comment: in my html file I want to add another row to the table that will display the currency

Comment: `<td>{{transaction.currency}}</td>` in your template

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Transaction.objects.filter(owner=request.user).values('currency', 'owner').annotate(amount_sum=Sum('amount'), total_price_sum=Sum('total_price'))
```

This will return something like this

```
<QuerySet [{'currency': 'BDT', 'owner': 1, 'amount_sum': 123, 'total_price_sum': Decimal('90')}, {'currency': 'USD', 'owner': 1, 'amount_sum': 11, 'total_price_sum': Decimal('30')}]>
```